# OS X Migration Assistant can't see Time Machine drive

Tags: time-machine, macos, backup, migration-assistant

I've wiped my machine (to start over), and I'd like to restore some key files back (like pictures and stuff like that).

However, when I connect my Time Machine drive and open Migration Assistant, it can't find my Time Machine drive. I've even tried logging in as root and invoking the application; no dice. It can see one of my *old* machine's backup (pre-2009), but that's not really the one I want.

It might be a problem that the name of my machine somehow was changed to 'iMac 1 (2)' - and thus the folder in Backups.backupdb is named the same - could that be tripping up Migration Assistant?

Comment: Are you comfortable in terminal? When you mount the drive in finder, can you navigate to a recent backup time stamp folder?

Comment: Yep - everything's there, it's just a problem of getting Migration Assistant to see the drive.

Comment: So - what does `ls -la` show for the machine directories and next level?